# Recipient "" has too many recent signup requests

Tags: jquery, mailchimp

I have one form created in HTML and I am trying to send form data to the MailChimp. I had used the GET method and their action into my code.

The ajax call works properly

but I am getting the response like

```
jQuery34005084585257053369_1557187883683({result: "error", msg: "Recipient "" has too many recent signup requests"})
msg: "Recipient "" has too many recent signup requests"
result: "error"
```

I have designed my own form only added action into it.
is there any solution for it??

is it require to change

'name' attributes for all inputs in my form to the same as in MailChimp 'name' attributes.

I tried that also but still getting the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create The same fields in the MailChimp signup forms as you have created on your HTML file.

MailChimp creates a form with action and unique names in all fields.

when you pass data to MailChimp using ajax or using a different method you need to pass all the names in the form same as MailChimp form.

The names should match with the names in the MailChimp signup forms.

also, both the form fields and their values should be the same (also matters case sensitivity).